# get all attributes of an html element using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

How can I get all attributes of an HTML element?
For example I have an element:

```
<input type="text" class"cls1" id="myId" name="myName"/>
```

and I want to see all attributes/properties that can be used for this input and not only attribute assigned already (type, class, id, name) on but all available attributes that can be used on this element.

With this method I can see only assigned attributes :|

```
var attr = document.getElementById("myId").attributes;
console.log(attr);
```

Comment: This thread answers the question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48339367/how-to-get-all-possible-valid-attributes-on-a-dom-element/48374988#48374988

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var el = document.getElementById("myId");

var nodes=[], values=[];
for (var att, i = 0, atts = el.attributes, n = atts.length; i < n; i++){
    att = atts[i];
    nodes.push(att.nodeName);
    values.push(att.nodeValue);
    console.log(att.nodeName + " - " + att.nodeValue);
}
```

Comment: I want to see all available atributes/properties that I can use on for that element ...

Answer (score 3):

Try **`console.dir()`**.

```
console.dir(document.getElementById('myId'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this,

```js
var attr = document.getElementById("myId").attributes;
for (var key in attr) {
  if (typeof attr[key] != 'function')
    console.log(attr[key]);
}
```

Comment: this return what I already have and not all attributes available for that element

Answer (score 1):

```js
var attr = document.getElementById("myId").attributes;
for (var key in attr) {
    var element = attr[key];
    if (typeof element === "object") {
        console.log(element.name);
        console.log(element.value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get all the enumerable properties using

```
var el = document.getElementById("myId");
var props = Object.keys(el); //will return an array of properties
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uguoumb5/)

[Object.Keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Browser_compatibility) - For [older browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Browser_compatibility) use a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Polyfill)

Comment: I want to see all available atributes/properties that I can use on for that element ...